# Kubernetes Route53 external-dns issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, amazon-eks

I am running a K8S cluster in AWS with EKS and external-DNS with an ingress-Nginx-ingress-controller. Application is working fine and accessible on load-balancer. Now I am trying to point my DNS to this cluster i.e. e1.exapmle.com and for this, I am following below documentation.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns

The issue I am facing is that I have two AWS accounts (QA, Staging) and hosted zones are created in staging account and the cluster is running on QA account. I have tried cross-account IAM roles for this to work but I can only see hosted zones via the web console, cli or external-DNS pods are not able to able to communicate with Route53.

This is what I have done so far:

Create an IAM policy

```
   {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "route53:ListHostedZones",
            "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Create a cross-account IAM role trusting account staging and trusted account QA.

Assum policy in the trusted account by specifying IAM role ARN for the above policy.

By doing above I only managed to see hosted zones via web console when I switch roles.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you provided a role arn of a role in the EKS account to the extern-dns pods which is allowed to assume to role inside you HostedZone account!?

This will not work because then (as you do inside the console) you need to explicitly assume the role with existing permissions.

You need to pass the Cross-Account role with your attached route53 policy directly to the external-dns pods.

Pod -> assumes role in different account -> receives temp. credentials

pod -> assumed role in eks account (-> allowd to assume cross-accout role)
last step won’t happen i guess

Comment: Yes, I did provide arn of Route53 role. I am assuming policy in account where EKS cluster is created.

Comment: did you find a solution?